# Cannot Update SQL Server Database

Tags: java, sql-server

In Sql Server Management Studio, i am updating database with keeping ID as primary key. From  ComboBox ,i am displaying all ID and after clicking on submit button all details are displayed in jTextField correspondig to different labels having name as column in database. Here my all details are displayed getting correctly. And there is reset button which removes details of some label, even i am getting correct this alos. But i can not update tables .
I am writing the code below. Please help and whats wrong into code;

```
package corejavaproject;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UpdateDetails extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

public UpdateDetails() 
{
    initComponents();
    com_view();
}
 private void com_view()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://AMISH-PC:1433;databaseName=Student","sa","comprishu");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String str ="select ID from Details;";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }     
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText("Department");

    jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 15)); // NOI18N

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel8.setText("Email");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("Aggregate Marks");

    jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel9.setText("Phone");

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("Update Details");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Name");

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setText("Campus Eligibilty");

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Submit");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Reset");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("Update");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 15)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Select Student ID");

    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    jButton4.setText("Back");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("ID");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(104, 104, 104)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(7, 7, 7))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                            .addComponent(jButton3)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(244, 244, 244)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(26, 26, 26))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(9, 9, 9)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jButton4))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(653, 511));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String str = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    try
    {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://AMISH-PC:1433;databaseName=Student","sa","comprishu");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String s1 = "Select * from Details where ID='"+str+"'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(s1);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String id = rs.getString(1);  
            String name = rs.getString(2);  
            String department = rs.getString(3);  
            Float f = rs.getFloat(4);  
            String marks = Float.toString(f);
            String ce = rs.getString(5);
            String email = rs.getString(6);
            String mobile = rs.getString(7);

            jTextField2.setText(name);
            jTextField1.setText(department);
            jTextField5.setText(marks);
            jTextField3.setText(ce);
            jTextField4.setText(email);
            jTextField6.setText(mobile);   
            jTextField7.setText(id); 

        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getSource()==jButton2)
    {

        //jTextField2.setText("");
        //jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField5.setText("");
        jTextField3.setText("");
        jTextField4.setText("");
        jTextField6.setText("");   
        //jTextField7.setText("");   
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if(evt.getSource()==jButton3)
    {
        String str = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        try
        {
            String st5=jTextField5.getText();
            Float f5 = Float.parseFloat(st5);
            String st3=jTextField3.getText();
            String st4=jTextField4.getText();
            String st6=jTextField6.getText();
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://AMISH-PC:1433;databaseName=Student","sa","comprishu");
            String query = "Update Details set Aggregate Marks=?,Campus Eligibilty=?,Email=?,Mobile=? where ID='"+str+"'";
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
            int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query); 
            stmt.setString(4,st5);
            stmt.setString(5,st3);
            stmt.setString(6,st4);
            stmt.setString(7,st6);   
        } 
        catch (    ClassNotFoundException | SQLException exp) 
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    new Home().setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UpdateDetails.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UpdateDetails.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UpdateDetails.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UpdateDetails.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new UpdateDetails().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Error are:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The method executeUpdate() cannot take arguments on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1566)
at corejavaproject.UpdateDetails.jButton3ActionPerformed(UpdateDetails.java:298)
at corejavaproject.UpdateDetails.access$200(UpdateDetails.java:14)
at corejavaproject.UpdateDetails$3.actionPerformed(UpdateDetails.java:114)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: r u sure the column names have spaces in them "Aggregate Marks=?,Campus Eligiblity=?", in ur update qry? Look at the table structure once.

Comment: wat do u get as exception in the console.

Comment: Mr.Arvind, there was spelling mistake in column name which i corrected but still i am getting same errors.

Comment: try this: "int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);" instead "int rs = stmt.executeUpdate();" at line no. 300

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part:

```
String query = "Update Details set Aggregate Marks=?,Campus Eligibilty=?,Email=?,Mobile=? where ID='"+str+"'";
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query); 
stmt.setString(4,st5);
stmt.setString(5,st3);
stmt.setString(6,st4);
stmt.setString(7,st6);
```

Your SQL contains placeholders (?), but you're calling `stmt.executeUpdate()` **before** you assign the values to those placeholders. You're also using the wrong numbers for those placeholders in those lines, it should be 1 to 4, not 4 to 7.

```
stmt.setString(1, st5);
stmt.setString(2, st3);
stmt.setString(3, st4);
stmt.setString(4, st6);
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(); // shouldn't need to pass query back in
```